# Jquery return new focus when switching with the tab button

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, focus

I have a function that adds / removes a class when changing focus between elements on my page.

When switching focus with a mouse click the desired effect is produced but when switching with the tab button it seems to read the focus before switching to the new element?

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="text-input">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input placeholder="">
</div>

<div class="text-input">
     <label>First Name</label>
    <input placeholder="">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").click(function () {activateInput($(this))});
    $('body').keydown(function(e) {
         var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == '9') {activateInput($(this))}
    });
});


function activateInput(passThis) {
    $(".text-input input, .text-input label").removeClass("active");
    if ($(".text-input input").is(":focus")) {
    $(":focus").parent().children("label, input").addClass("active");
    }
}
```

**Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/4kdj7Luc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use keyup

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("body").click(function () {activateInput()});
    $('body').keyup(function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == 9) {activateInput();}
    });
});


function activateInput() {
    $(".text-input input, .text-input label").removeClass("active");
    $(':focus').parent().children("label, input").addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: Duh. How did I not think of that? Thank you!